# Слайдер, галерея на сайт с навигацией элементы состоят из текста и изображения

Tags: javascript, html, css, слайдер

Всем привет, ищу готовое (или почти готовое) решение для слайдера-галереи.

Особенность в том, что бы можно было управлять слайдами как при клике на кошек, так и при помощи кнопок.

Так же необходимо что бы слайды состояли не только из рисунков и из текста, название кошки, ее описание.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в наше время наверное любой мало-мальски адекватный слайдер имеет событийную модель, которая позволяет обрабатывать события слайдера и управлять его поведением с помощью js. Возьмите какой-нить Slick, там есть режим синхронного просмотра. Хотя скрипт под эти цели самостоятельно написать будет быстрее, чем изучить слайдер.

Comment: или взять swiper slider, у которого очень здоровый api

Comment: Можете использовать сторонние библиотеки,там все с документацией и примерами,рекомендую Framework7 https://framework7.io/docs/swiper.html если не понравится можете поискать и что то другое в интернете,таких библиотек много.